# Triggering callback without pressing the button in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, security-framework, sfauthorizationpluginview

I need to be able to start the authentication process in [this sample](https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword) without pressing the button provided by default.

The action I want to run is the -(void)buttonPressed method, but if I try to invoke it manually the plugin crashes. It's invoked automatically by pressing that button but it would be nice to be able to just press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should all be obvious after a single glance in the plugin source code you linked!**

While it shouldn't crash (after a quick look into the class code), you probably do not supply the appropriate sender when sending buttonPressed: from your code. The method is defined as

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(SFButtonType)inButtonType
```

Which clearly shows the button that was pressed is given as sender. So in your code when calling `buttonPressed:` do for example like:

```
["referenceRToClass" buttonPressed:SFButtonTypeOK];
```

Comment: The point is, I ran [self buttonPressed:SFButtonTypeOK] and it has crashed. I'll provide the crash report as soon as I get back to my Mac.

Comment: then instead just pass a reference to the button using an IBOutlet.

Comment: I don't know how to create an outlet to this button - it's not present in the nib file(you can take a look). Instead, it's generated somehow when the plugin is active in the system. I believe this is why they created a callback instead of letting us do this.

Comment: hm, when the button is generated on the fly, you still should be able to iterate over the UI elements and identify this one button due to its type... yet, better post the cars report, maybe the reason is another one than the button...

Comment: I found the problem - the plugin was crashing not because I was calling the method wrong, but because I wanted to execute the code before the username has been read from the system. Now that I have setup a time delay of few miliseconds it works fine. Thanks, but I have another small question - how could I detect the enter key press in this app? I would try creating an outlet, but it doesn't want to work by click-dragging. Could you take a look at this? It's probably this sample is very old.

Comment: you can detect key presses by using implementing keyDown: for example in an object that is in the responder chain...

Comment: turns out creating actions for this nssecuretextfield was possible only after disabling 32-bit machines from build targets. Thanks anyway! :)